# Puppet -- how to get what all packages are installed, files are created on a node?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

We have a bunch of puppet manifests bootstrapping nodes. Most of it is legacy code written by many authors.

Instead of looking at the puppet manifests and understanding what has been installed, is it possible to use any puppet command(s) to simply print all the packages, files etc that are being installed/created on a given node?

Comment: You could look at the returned reports ( https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/reporting_about.html ) or fetch the compiled manifest for each node and inspect those.

Comment: Note: the standard Puppet terminology for a "compiled manifest [set]" is a "catalog".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks.  Been far too long since I’ve used Puppet

Comment: @PatrickM Comment is very likely best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should find everything you need in /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/resources.txt